# Migrar EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH,data) de MySQL para SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma query em MySQL que precisaria converter para SQL Server.

Tentei com `datepart` do SQL Server porém ele não mantém a principal característica da query do MySQL, que é manter o range mês a mês mas também levar em consideração os treinamentos que se estenderem por mais de um mês.

Segue o SELECT usado no MySQL:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
   *
FROM
   treinamentos,usuario_x_treinamento,usuario
WHERE
   status_treinamento = 'REALIZADO' 
   AND
      '201705' BETWEEN
      EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM treinamentos.data_inicio_treinamento) AND
      EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM treinamentos.data_fim_treinamento)
   AND
      usuario_x_treinamento.id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario
   AND
      usuario_x_treinamento.id_treinamento = treinamentos.id_treinamentos;
```

Em SQL Server ficou até agora algo como:

```sql
SELECT count(DISTINCT usuario.id_usuario) as TREINADO,
FROM treinamentos, usuario_x_treinamento, usuario
WHERE 
datepart(YEAR, treinamentos.data_inicio_treinamento) = '2017'
and datepart(YEAR, treinamentos.data_fim_treinamento) = '2017'
AND DATEPART(MONTH, treinamentos.data_inicio_treinamento) = '01'
and DATEPART(month, treinamentos.data_fim_treinamento) = '01'
AND usuario_x_treinamento.id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario
and status_treinamento = 'REALIZADO'
AND usuario_x_treinamento.id_treinamento = treinamentos.id_treinamentos;
```

Porém como eu já havia dito, esse select só está me retornando treinamento que iniciaram E terminaram em Janeiro de 2017. Eu preciso que sejam contabilizados por exemplo treinamento que iniciaram em Outubro de 2016 e tenham sido finalizado em Agosto de 2017.

Comment: Poderia postar um exemplo dos dados que você está tentando utilizar os comandos SQL, porque ai fica mais claro entender como estava o resultado e comparar com o resultado do sqlserver. Se puder utilizar alguma ferramenta como o sqlfiddle.com, fica mais fácil para a comunidade te ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eis sugestões que procuram simular a construção utilizada no MySQL:

```
-- código #1
...
where 201705 between 
      (year(treinamentos.data_inicio_treinamento) * 100 + month(treinamentos.data_inicio_treinamento)) and
      (year(treinamentos.data_fim_treinamento) * 100 + month(treinamentos.data_fim_treinamento)) 
...
```

ou então

```
-- código #2
...
where '201705' between 
      convert(char(6), treinamentos.data_inicio_treinamento, 112) and
      convert(char(6), treinamentos.data_fim_treinamento, 112) 
...
```

Comment: muito obrigado. Utilizei o código #1 e funcionou perfeitamente.
Somente uma dúvida: Qual seria o de melhor desempenho em sua opinião?

Comment: Matheus, o código #2 se parece mais com o código do MySQL, pois retorna _string_.  //  
Com relação ao desempenho, me parece que o primeiro passo é avaliar se a cláusula WHERE completa é _sargable_.

Answer (score 0):

Você quer o período '201705' enteja entre as datas de **treinamentos.data_inicio_treinamento** e **treinamentos.data_fim_treinamento**

Exitem algumas formas de fazer isso, você precisa testar pra ver a performance, mas poderia fazer:

```
WHERE treinamentos.data_inicio_treinamento >= '20170501'
  AND treinamentos.data_fim_treinamento < '20170601'
```

outra forma seria:

```
WHERE FORMAT(treinamentos.data_inicio_treinamento, 'yyyyMM') >= '201705' 
  AND FORMAT(treinamentos.data_fim_treinamento , 'yyyyMM') <= '201705'
```

A função `FORMAT` tende a ser mais lenta, mas depende do volume de dados da sua tabela, vale a pena testar.

Comment: estou fazendo alguns testes com esse trecho que me enviou, obrigado pelo retorno.

Comment: Olá @ricardo-pontual, o trecho não funcionou como o esperado, este código só está me trazendo treinamento num período de um Mês, o que eu preciso é que retorne o mesmo treinamento N vezes durante o **período** que o mesmo ficou aberto por exemplo data_inicio : 01/01/2018 data_fim: 31/03/2018, **preciso que este treinamento apareça na consulta de janeiro,fevereiro e março**, pois ele se estendeu por 3 meses.

Comment: mas esse período está fora do 201705 certo? acredito que você precise adaptar para o período que deseja... esse exemplo que você deu nem na query do `MySQL` vai retornar